# Перегрузка операторов в абстрактном классе

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь создать абстрактный класс Iterator. Его наследники - классы Array_Iterator и List_Iterator. В этих классах переопределены операторы  *, ++, --, ==, !=, -.

```
   template <typename T>
class Array_Iterator : public Iterator<T> {
    friend class Vector<T>;

protected:
    Vector<T>* m_array;
    T* m_ptr;

public:
    Array_Iterator() : m_array(nullptr), m_ptr(nullptr) {};

    Array_Iterator(Vector<T>* array, T* ptr) : m_array(array), m_ptr(ptr) {};

    T& operator*() override {
        if (*this == m_array->end())
            throw std::runtime_error("\n(Array_Iterator) operator *: index out of range\n");
        return *m_ptr;
    }

    Array_Iterator& operator++() override {
        if (*this == m_array->end())
            throw std::runtime_error("\n(Array_Iterator) operator ++: index out of range\n");
        ++m_ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    Array_Iterator& operator--() override{
        if (*this == m_array->begin())
            throw std::runtime_error("\n(Array_Iterator) operator --: index out of range\n");
        --m_ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    friend bool operator== (const Array_Iterator &it1, const Array_Iterator &it2) { return it1.m_ptr == it2.m_ptr; }
    friend bool operator!= (const Array_Iterator &it1, const Array_Iterator &it2) { return it1.m_ptr != it2.m_ptr; }

    friend int operator- (const Array_Iterator &it1, const Array_Iterator &it2) { return it1.m_ptr - it2.m_ptr; }
};
```

Класс List_Iterator выглядит аналогично Array_Iterator.

```
template <typename T>
class Iterator {
public:
    virtual T& operator*() = 0;
    virtual Iterator<T>& operator++() = 0;
    virtual Iterator<T>& operator--() = 0;

    friend bool operator== (const Iterator<T>& it1, const Iterator<T>& it2) { return it1 == it2; }
    friend bool operator!= (const Iterator<T>& it1, const Iterator<T>& it2) { return it1 != it2; }
    friend bool operator- (const Iterator<T>& it1, const Iterator<T>& it2) { return it1 - it2; }

};
```

Сложности возникли с операторами ==, != и -, так как они перегружены через дружественные функции. Если сделать так как у меня сейчас, при попытке написать следующее

```
template <typename T>
void test(Iterator<T>& b, Iterator<T>& e) {
    std::cout << (e == b);
}
```

возникает ошибка "operator==: рекурсия на всех путях выполнения, функция вызовет переполнение стека", и это понятно почему - операторы ==, != и - просто вызывают сами себя. Но как сделать правильно - не могу понять. Есть только идея переделать перегрузку операторов не через дружественные функции. Но есть ли какой-то способ оставить такую реализацию? Подскажите пожалуйста что-нибудь по этому вопросу.

Comment: Если у вас функционал внутри тот же, вызывайте [базовый оператор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734846/calling-operators-of-base-class-safe)

Comment: ¿Зачем тут наследование? ¿По какому принципу вы собираетесь сравнивать итераторы для разных видов контейнеров?

Comment: @user7860670 Нет, сравнивать итераторы для разных видов не надо. Мне надо написать универсальную сортировку: `void sort(Iterator<T>& begin, Iterator<T>& end, int (*cmp)(const T& x, const T& y)`. И у меня есть два контейнера, List и Array. В сортировку может быть передан как `List_Iterator`, так и `Array_Iterator`.

Comment: Согласно принципу подстановки функция вида `void sort(Iterator<T>& begin, Iterator<T>& end` *обязана* работать с итераторами разных контейнеров. Если это не так, то и наследование неправильное. Принимайте вместо `Iterator<T>` шаблонный тип итератор, как то делают алгоритмы из стандартной библиотеки.